# How to hide a Bootstrap Popover when a new popover is shown?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4

I need to show a popover in a certain condition to give a hint to user. This hint should be hidden automatically in 5 seconds. This is the AngularJS code for that:

```
$('#popoverLocationId')
   .popover('show') // shows immediately
   .on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
        var pop = $(this);
        timerForHide = $interval(function () {
            pop.popover('hide');
        }, 5000, 1);
    });
```

*(For hiding, i use $interval with count 1 instead of $timeout since i also want to protractor-test this case, and $timeout does not play nicely with protractor. But this does not play any role for my actual problem)*

Since this certain condition (where i need to show the popover) can also occur multiple times within 5 seconds, i do not want to show the same popover twice overlapping, instead i have to close the current one (if any), and open a new one with a new 5 second duration. That's why i save a reference of interval-hide timer and try to cancel it like this:

```
$interval.cancel(timerForHide);            // cancelling the current 5 seconds hide-timer
$('#popoverLocationId').popover('hide');   // hide popover immediately

...  shows a new popover with the above code..
```

The problem is, the new popover is still somehow affected by the first one's duration. when i open multiple popovers within 5 seconds, i see the current popover is closed, the new one is opened, but it will be shown just for 1-2 seconds, as if the timer of the first one still lives and somehow affects the new popover.

Can you see what may cause this issue?

**EDIT**: I think this has sth to do with the definition of hide-interval inside the callback "shown.bs.popover". When i rewrite the code like this it works well:

```
$interval(function () {
  $('#popoverLocationId').popover('show');
}, 500, 1);

timerForHide = $interval(function () {
  $('#popoverLocationId').popover('hide');
}, 5000, 1);
```

And again i can call  *$interval.cancel(timerForHide);*  from outside and it really cancels it. I think i have solved my problem for now. But i dont know if it is really nice to have 2 independent show/hide sections. On my first approach, hide was being initialized just after the show runs (callback shown.bs.popover).

Comment: Instead of hiding have you tried disposing? `.popover('dispose')`

Comment: yes. when i dispose, i don't see the popover anymore.. i mean, it will never be shown again

Comment: @AkberIqbal why "if there is a popover opened, don't open another". As i wrote above, i would like to close the current one, and open a new one. I can't see how your suggestion helps me..

Comment: @AkberIqbal please read the question carefully.. i am not asking for a way of handling visibility.. i just cannot stop the interval of the current popover affecting the duration of new one.